# Error al trabajar con foreach

Tags: php, html

Buenas tardes, al tratar de traer imágenes de la base de datos la página me manda los siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined variable: fotos in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoCarrito2\views\index.view.php on line 72
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoCarrito2\views\index.view.php on line 72

En la parte del `index.php` tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <?php


session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['idUsuario']) && empty($_SESSION['Tipo'])){
    include 'conexion.php';
    include 'views/index.view.php';


    $fotos_por_pagina = 16;

    $pagina_actual = (isset($_GET['p']) ? (int)$_GET['p'] : 1);
    $inicio = ($pagina_actual > 1) ? $pagina_actual * $fotos_por_pagina - $fotos_por_pagina : 0;

    $conexion = conexion('proyecto', 'root', '');

    if (!$conexion) {
        die();
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM timagen LIMIT $inicio, $fotos_por_pagina
    ");

    $statement->execute();
    $fotos = $statement->fetchAll();

    if (!$fotos) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_filas");
    $statement->execute();
    $total_post = $statement->fetch()['total_filas'];

    $total_paginas = ceil($total_post / $fotos_por_pagina);
}else{

header("Location: formularios/form_cliente.php");
}


?>
```

Y en la parte de la vista que es index.view.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<article class="imagenes col-9 col-m-8">
    <?php foreach($fotos as $foto):?>
        <div class="col-4 col-m-6">
        <a href="fotos.php?id=<?php echo $foto['idImagen']; ?>">
            <img src="images/bd<?php echo $foto['Imagen'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $foto['Descripcion'] ?>">
        </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</article>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Es un buen diseño, aparentemente MVC. **Pero** la vista necesita recibir los datos que debe mostrar. **¿De qué manera pasas los datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos al archivo `index.view.php`?** Eso es lo que PHP te reclama cuando te dice _Undefined variable_. Generalmente en un diseño MVC la vista es una clase que recibe en parámetro los datos que debe mostrar, generalmente a través de una función de la clase dedicada a ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que hice fue poner el include del archivo, al final de mi código y se soluciono, en vez de el código anterior lo cambie por lo siguiente:

```
    <?php


session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['idUsuario']) && empty($_SESSION['Tipo'])){
    include 'conexion.php';


    $fotos_por_pagina = 16;

    $pagina_actual = (isset($_GET['p']) ? (int)$_GET['p'] : 1);
    $inicio = ($pagina_actual > 1) ? $pagina_actual * $fotos_por_pagina - $fotos_por_pagina : 0;

    $conexion = conexion('proyecto', 'root', '');

    if (!$conexion) {
        die();
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM timagen LIMIT $inicio, $fotos_por_pagina
    ");

    $statement->execute();
    $fotos = $statement->fetchAll();

    if (!$fotos) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_filas");
    $statement->execute();
    $total_post = $statement->fetch()['total_filas'];

    $total_paginas = ceil($total_post / $fotos_por_pagina);

include 'views/index.view.php';
}else{

header("Location: formularios/form_cliente.php");
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira en tu código HTML la sentencia [foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) tienes mal; para una sola instrucción:

```
foreach (expresión_array as $valor)
   sentencia
```

o

```
foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor)
   sentencia
```

para varias instrucciones

```
foreach (expresión_array as $valor) {
   sentencia1
   sentencia2
   sentencia3
   ...
   sentenciaN
}
```

o

```
foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor) {
   sentencia1
   sentencia2
   sentencia3
   ...
   sentenciaN
}
```

Para los casos `<?php echo CADENAoVALOR ?>` y similares te sugiero `<?= CADENAoVALOR ?>`; es una sola instrucción que usas el `echo`.

[foreach en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)